# Script SSH Interactive Console that needs escaped chars

Tags: bash, ssh, shell, escape-characters, escape-sequences

I would like to modify my existing SSH connection via a shell script. So if I run an existing script remotely I would like it to open a new port to be tunnelled.

Interactively I can do this via:

```
ubuntu@6c1a17c3864c:~$ ~C
ssh> -R 9000:localhost:9000
```

As put much more clearly than I could: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel.

Ideally I would like to use a shell script to interact via the escaped characters to adjust the existing connection.

I have looked at something like:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Attempt 1
echo -n '\r\f \~\~C -L 9000:localhost:9000'
# Attempt 2
echo -e '\r\f\~\C -R 9000:localhost:9000'
printf '\~\C -L 9000:localhost:9000'
netstat -taln
```

As well as a few other combinations.

I have verified that both echo and printf are shell builtins.

I'm using Bash 4.3.11 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.

Comment: you would probably need `expect` script to achieve this. But why? You can define port forwarding on command-line much easier.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to define a set of bash functions that could modify the existing ssh session. I'm not great at this really low level stuff. But can't see any reason it couldn't be done in bash. Expect might work well though. I'll see what I can do there to get it to play nicely.

Comment: The problem is that these escape chars are NOT evaluated by bash, but locally by your ssh client.

Comment: So the escape chars I want to send would need to be evaluated by the ssh client on my local machine right? Rather than bash on the remote end. Even sending this via tcl/expect then wouldn't evaluate it on the client side?

Comment: expect should do that, but I didn't try yet. [There are some references](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/expect-scripting-help-escape-characters-663046/).

Answer (score 0):

You would need `expect` script to achieve this. The problem is that these escape chars are NOT evaluated by bash, but locally by your ssh client. Example that should do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 10
 exp_internal 1
spawn telnet $argv
expect "login:"
send "mylogin\n"
expect "Password:"
send "mypass\n"
expect '~$'
# Send some commands
close
```

[Source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/expect-scripting-help-escape-characters-663046/)